# SP 2016 - Crawler Not Writing to Index

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, crawling

I am working in SharePoint 2016 with SharePoint search.  I have created a search topology that is as follows:

- Admin - Server01, Server02
- Crawl - Server01, Server02
- Content Processing - Server01, Server02
- Index - Server01, Server02
- Query - Server01, Server02
- Analytics - Server01, Server02

Now my problem is this, everything is working fine except for one thing - the crawler won't write to one of the index locations, Server01, but it writes fine on the other index location, Server02. I have checked the permissions on both Index folders and they are identical. I have checked event viewer for search related errors, on both servers this error appears:

"The crawl has been delayed because a disk is full. Check the system default temp location and the drive on which search catalog is created. The system default temp location is used for creation of temporary files during crawling. If it is full, crawling pauses. If the system default temp location is full, change the location to a disk with more free space and restart the computer. Changes to the system temp location do not take effect for system services until the computer is restarted."

However, this error does not prevent the crawler from writing to Server 02, so I'm thinking it is unrelated.

Has anyone else seen this problem?  Can you provide guidance to help me correct it?

Comment: Is the disk allocation the same on both servers? Is the index location available on both servers?

Comment: @Matthew - Both index drives have the same disk allocation - 300 GB. The index location is available and the same location - D:\SearchIndex. But on  Server01 the index storage is just 128 MB, while the Server02 the index storage is 168 GB.

Comment: What is your full farm topology? How many servers in total?

Comment: The full topology is as follows:

Comment: The full topology is as follows:

2 x Distributed Cache
2 x Search Servers
2 x WFE Servers
4 x Custom Servers (1 x PowerPivot, 3 x WFE)

Comment: I also have this search topology report:

IndexComponent4 | Degraded                          
Cell:IndexComponent4-SPa8a251837afdI.1.0        Degraded                          
IndexComponent5 | Active                            
Cell:IndexComponent5-SPa8a251837afdI.0.0 | Active

Comment: Partition:0 | Active                            
AdminComponent1 | Active                            
QueryProcessingComponent1 | Active                            
ContentProcessingComponent1  | Active                            
AnalyticsProcessingComponent1 | Active                            
AdminComponent2  | Active                            
QueryProcessingComponent2  | Active                            
ContentProcessingComponent2 | Active                            
AnalyticsProcessingComponent2  | Active

Comment: CrawlComponent4  | Active                            
CrawlComponent5  | Active

Comment: With 14 servers in your farm why are you using only 2 for search? I would move Index and Query to at least 2 of your WFEs. Maybe even move Admin + Crawl on to separate servers too for performance.

Comment: Yeah I agree, but this isn't my topology, it was set by another admin.  My problem is to get the second index to work.